# Using vim as default text editor for lynx

Tags: configuration, browser, lynx

I want to use vim as the text editor while opening a website using lynx.
How do I do it? I see a switch present in lynx as `-editor=EDITOR` but giving `-editor=vim` makes no difference to lynx.

Comment: On some systems, editing is permanently disabled for security reasons (e.g. on OpenBSD). What Unix are you using?

Comment: @Kusalananda: Ubuntu.

Comment: What is your `$EDITOR` variable set to?

Comment: @Panki: I gave complete path not used any variable. Like -editor=/usr/bin/vim.